# Find maximum score or the maximum average score of candidate scores given in two dim array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, java-stream

Question: Candidates can attempt an entrance exam as many times as they wish. The average score of all attempts is considered in the end. Given a list of scores. find the candidate with the highest score [ average score].

```
String scores[][] = {{"Ram","155"}, 
                    {"Shyam","145"},
                    {"Ram","156"},
                    {"Balram","159"},
                    {"Balram","150"},
                    {"Ram","135"},
                    {"Mira","156"},
                    {"Mira","152"},
                    {"Shyam","155"}};
```

Scores are given in two-dimensional array as above. Need suggestions to solve this in efficient way.

Comment: "Need suggestions to improve Time Complexity and Space Complexity." What do you think the time and space complexity of this code are; why do you think they need improvement, rather than other aspects of this code; how do you know they can be improved?

Comment: I think the time and space complexity is O(m + n ) where m is number of candidates and n is number of max attempts by a candidate. I did this using 2 loops and there ought to be better solutions.So sought the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the reason for reducing the time and space complexity? I strongly believe the brevity and maintainability are more important than the performance.

Since you tagged [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream), I can suggest you the following approach.

```
Map<Object, Double> scoreMap = Arrays.stream(scores)
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i[0], 
            Collectors.averagingInt(i -> Integer.parseInt(i[1])
        )));

String winner = scoreMap.entrySet().stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> e.getValue()))
    .get().getKey().toString();
```

Thanks to @AndyTurner for the `.max(..)` parameter suggestion.

Comment: `.max(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> e.getValue())`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Thank you for the note :))

Answer (score 1):

To reduce time complexity, you can use specific collections:

```
public static String findMaxScore(String[][] scores) {
    final class Candidate implements Comparable<Candidate> {

        private final String name;
        private int scoreSum;
        private int attempts;

        public Candidate(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void score(int score) {
            scoreSum += score;
            attempts++;
        }

        public double avg() {
            return (double)scoreSum / attempts;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Candidate candidate) {
            return Double.compare(candidate.avg(), avg());
        }
    }

    Map<String, Candidate> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String[] data : scores) {
        map.putIfAbsent(data[0], new Candidate(data[0]));
        map.get(data[0]).score(Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
    }

    return new TreeSet<>(map.values()).iterator().next().name;
}
```

Comment: Creating a class to store and compare the candidates details like above is more efficient than processing the data  directly using java streams like suggested in other answer?

Comment: @SatishK yes. this is exaple. Class could be defined out of the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String  findmaxAverage(String[][] Grades) {
    if ( grades == null ) return "";
    Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for( String[] grade : Grades ) {
        List<Integer> mapList = map.get(grade[0]);
        if ( mapList == null ) mapList = new ArrayList<>();
        mapList.add(Integer.valueOf(grade[1]));
        map.put(grade[0], mapList);
    }

    double maxAverage = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    String winner = "";
    for( String name : map.nameSet()) {
        System.out.println(name+": "+map.get(name));
        List<Integer> mapList = map.get(name);
        double average = getAverage(mapList);
        if ( average > maxAverage) {
            maxAverage = average;
            winner = name;
        }

    }
    return winner; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, by this way, You can do the same via `Streams` Api,

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    String scores[][] = {{"Bob","80"},{"Charles","85"},{"Rob","70"},{"Bob","100"},{"Charles","75"}};
    

 Map<Object,Double> collectValues = Arrays.stream(scores).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a->a[0],Collectors.averagingInt(a->Integer.parseInt(a[1]))));

    Map.Entry<Object,Double> MaxMarks = collectValues.entrySet().stream().max((e1,e2)->Double.compare(e1.getValue(), e2.getValue())).get();

    System.out.println(MaxMarks.getKey() + " :: " + MaxMarks.getValue());

}
```